# Return to back-stacked fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have fragments A, B, C which I add with `add()` method.

When I reach fragment C, at some point I want to go back to fragment A and remove B and C.

My approach:

```
val backStateName = FragmentA::class.java.name
activity.fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
```

I also have a `specialTag` added to my fragment A, so I did a check to make sure, that before I try my approach, fragment A is still in back stack.

```
val fragmentToGoTo = activity.fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(specialTag)
```

and it doesn't return null - which means fragment is still available in back stack.     `popBackStackImmediate` returns false. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you attach a fragment (or perform any other action s.a. add/remove/detach etc.), you have an option to add it to the backstack with a name String:

```
FragmentA fragmentA = (FragmentA) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("A");
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
if (fragmentA != null) {
    transaction.attach(fragmentA);
    transaction.addToBackStack("attachA");
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Notice the "attachA" String we passed to the addToBackStack() method. We'll later use it to go back. Assume we've performed other transactions - added/removed/attached/detached some other fragments. Now to get back to the state we were call one of the popBackStack() methods:

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack("attachA", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

If there was a transaction added to the back stack with the name "attachA" - the method will take us back to that state.

Regarding your question about the return case - you've probably read the documentation about these methods and what values they return. I prefer to use the popBackStack() since it

```
/**
 * Pop the last fragment transition from the manager's fragment
 * back stack.  If there is nothing to pop, false is returned.
 * This function is asynchronous -- it enqueues the
 * request to pop, but the action will not be performed until the application
 * returns to its event loop.
 * 
 * @param name If non-null, this is the name of a previous back state
 * to look for; if found, all states up to that state will be popped.  The
 * {@link #POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE} flag can be used to control whether
 * the named state itself is popped. If null, only the top state is popped.
 * @param flags Either 0 or {@link #POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE}.
 */
public abstract void popBackStack(String name, int flags);

/**
 * Like {@link #popBackStack(String, int)}, but performs the operation immediately
 * inside of the call.  This is like calling {@link #executePendingTransactions()}
 * afterwards.
 * @return Returns true if there was something popped, else false.
 */
public abstract boolean popBackStackImmediate(String name, int flags);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same behaviour. Make sure that you call `popBackStackImmediate` on the same Thread as you used to add it to your backstack.

Also verify that you use `.add()` instead of `.replace()`

Anyway, it's never guaranteed that the backstack is not cleared/destroyed while doing this. I solved this behaviour by just using `popBackStack()` until you reach the fragment which you want to have.

You may try something like:

```
fun popStack(tag: String) {
  var isPopped =  fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(tag, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
  if (!isPopped) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack() 
      //maybe a loop until you reached your goal.
  }
}
```

Comment: tag represents fragments tag or fragments class name?

Comment: The tag you used to add it to backstack. In your example it's the classname